# Cannot install Deepin Desktop Environment on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

So as per the instructions, I've already added the ppa repo, and updated.
But when I run:

```
# apt install dde
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dde : Depends: dde-desktop but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-polkit-agent but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-dock but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-launcher but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-control-center (> 2.90.5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-daemon but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: deepin-metacity but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: deepin-wm but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: startdde but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-session-ui but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: deepin-notifications but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: deepin-menu but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: deepin-terminal but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-calendar but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: deepin-system-monitor but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: deepin-image-viewer but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: deepin-screenshot but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: deepin-deb-installer but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: deepin-screen-recorder but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: deepin-voice-recorder but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: deepin-shortcut-viewer but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a fix to this?

Edit: I have already tried the aptitude and synaptic methods. Aptitude reduced my dependencies by maybe 2, and synaptic says that I need to fix broken packages first. When trying the commands `sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..r` and `apt-mark showhold` I get no results.

Edit 2: I have tried the solutions from the second duplicate claim too, no luck.

Comment: I ask to reopen the question.
Both of the resolution links, do not solve the problem, I have his same problem.